# CakePHP not redirecting after opening new window with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

In one of my actions I'm adding items to a shopping cart on an external website via a javascript window. After they're added then I redirect back to a home page, however, CakePHP isn't redirecting. The items are being added to the cart correctly.

```
//OrdersController

function place_filled_orders($id = null){
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    ?>
        <script>
            cart_window = window.open("http://www.example.com/load_cart_with_stuff");
            cart_window.close();
        </script>
    <?
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'home'));
}
```

When I click on the link that corresponds to this action, it just stays on /orders/place_filled_orders rather than redirecting to /orders/home

Comment: What are you doing?! This is 100% against MVC rules. Scripts go in your view! Never in your controller.

Comment: @Oldskool There isn't supposed to be a view for this action. Assuming I do put it in the view, how do I then redirect once I'm in the view?

Comment: Why are Earth are you redirecting with JavaScript (in your controller no less) rather than just doing whatever you need to do and then redirecting using `$this->redirect('some/url');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add scripts in your Controller that way. It's totally against MVC rules and you should therefor avoid it. You should add a view (or element) that does both actions:

So add a `app/View/Orders/place_filled_order.ctp` file with something like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('
    cart_window = window.open("http://www.example.com/load_cart_with_stuff");
    cart_window.close();
    window.location.href = "' . $this->webroot . '/orders/home";
');
```

**Edit**

At second glance, it actually looks like you are looking for the [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) method instead. So you'll get your controller to look like:

```
function place_filled_orders($id = null) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->requestAction('/load_cart_with_stuff');
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'home'));
}
```

Comment: Will I still use that code you posted in the view? (minus the redirect)

Comment: You use one or the other, not both. If the window that is to be opened is inside your app, use the requestAction method, you don't need a view then. If it's an external resource, the javascript bit is the only solution.

Comment: it's an external resource, so I suppose the javascript is the way to go. Thanks for your help!